# HQL Hibernate order by

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have a complicated query (that I have simplified for this question), which requires me to use approaches beyond findAll, findBy, ect. 
There are multiple entities being brought together with the general form...

`PackageDelivery` has a `customer_id` column which is linked to a `Customer`. I need to order the results by the `PackageDelivery.customer.lastName`;
currently I'm using `createSQLQuery` to get the results. Since the customer entity is pulled in by Hibernate and not by my native SQL query though, I can't just add order by `package_delivery.customer.last_name`. Is there a way to order by entity properties Hibernate pulls in from native SQL queries??

```
select * from PackageDelivery 
inner join PackageContents
left join  ProductBillingInfo
```

Quite a few conditions and specifics are added, but that's the general idea.

PackageDelivery has a 'customer_id' column which is linked to a Customer. I need to order the results by the PackageDelivery.customer.lastName;
Currently I'm using createSQLQuery to get the results. Since the customer entity is pulled in by Hibernate and not by my native SQL query though, I can't just add order by package_delivery.customer.last_name. Is there a way to order by entity properties Hibernate pulls in from native SQL queries??

```
select {pd*.},{tl.*},{pc.*} from package_delivery as pd
inner join transport_log on tl.package_id=pd.id
left join package_contents on pd.id=pc.package_id
//order by pd.customer
def session =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
def lookup=session.createSQLQuery(que)
.setParameter('startDate',startdate)
.setParameter('endDate',enddate)
.addEntity('pd', ProductDelivery.class)
.addEntity('tl', TransportLog.class)
//need to sort by ProductDelivery.customer.lastName??
//.setResultTransformer( to???)
//.addOrder(Order.desc(to???)
```

Comment: In the hibernate docu there is an join - order example: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add that customer class like {c} and use .addEntity('c', Customer.class) and then use the order by c.last_name.
and make  the relation of the Customer and the ProductDelivery

Comment: ended up doing something similar.